# Visual Studio 2008 Hangs When Publishing Web Site

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-applications

Recently, I restructured and moved around some projects on my file system for better maintability.  Now, all of my projects compile but everytime I attempt to publish a web site project, Visual Studio 2008 hangs while attempting to publish a specific directory.  Below is a snapshot of what I see in the Output before it hangs.  It always hangs on "Publishing directory Images..."  Are there some other logs or resources that I can use to determine why Visual Studio 2008 stops responding when publishing this directory?  I've restarted VS and rebooted to no avail.  Any suggestions/comments are greatly appreciated.

```
Publishing directory Css...
Publishing directory Documentation...
publishing directory Documents...
publishing directory Images... (Visual Studio 2008 Stops Responding Here Every Time)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go figure, I had to completely shut down my laptop and pull the power cord for a few minutes before rebooting.  Then, I was able to publish again.